# Angular controller not accessible in production

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a Symfony project, and as the vast majority working on more than one environments: dev and production, using Angular.js.

At the moment, I have got an Angular controller which is accessible in dev environment, but not in production, throwing the message: "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'xxxx' is not a function, got undefined".
I have seen the latter message in several threads but none of them helped me.

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, MyMapper, _, moment, APP_URL, $location) {

$scope.APP_URL = APP_URL;
$scope.momentjs = moment;
$scope.isLoading = 1;
$scope.page = 1;
$scope.totalPagesNum = 1;
$scope.limit = 20;


// fill the table with data
MyMapper.find($location.search()).then(function(data) {

         // ... 
    })();
}).then(function() {
    $scope.isLoading = false;
});
```

});

Comment: Your error message really has 'xxxx' in it?

Comment: No, it is actually 'MyController'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should have "function($scope," instead of "function MyController($scope,". Nothing to do with Symfony 2.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is did not work.
The thing is that I can access the controller and the page normally in development environment.

Comment: Did you try the ever popular cache clearing?  Does your web server logs indicate the server is being hit?  Seems very strange.  Looks like the tags on your question got changed.

Comment: Yes, I did. Very strange.
I have just noticed also the change on the tags; this should be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are minimizing your code (as would be typical in production), you will want to annotate your dependencies since they may get renamed by the minimization script.  In order to do this, use the following pattern for your code:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('MyController', 
    ['$scope','MyMapper','_','momemt','APP_URL','$location',
        function($scope, MyMapper, _, moment, APP_URL, $location) {
            /* your code for the controller */
        }
    ]
);
```

Please see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di for more information, particularly the "Dependency Annotation" section and the inline array notation subsection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Brad.
I have just tried that but it still does not work.

Maybe the fact it works normally in dev environment and not in production environment indicates something else ?

Comment: Could indicate a lot of things.  It's hard to tell without seeing your production scripts.  Maybe your bundle/min script is missing that file.  If you view source and open your minified file, do you see those strings ('$scope','MyMapper',etc..) for that controller?  If not, it may just be missing your file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is pretty much solved.

It turns out that the minified version of vendors.js (vendros.min.js), was not properly loaded in the production environment. Therefore, I had to point to the correct  one in my Gruntfile.js.

Secondly, I refactored my controllers according to AngularJS online guide, as per Brad.

Thanks everyone involved.